# How do I get a list of baking rights for a wallet address using the RPC API?

Tags: baking, node, rpc

Using the tezos node, is there an RPC command from the API that allows one to retrieve the baking rights of any given address for a given cycle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
GET ../<block_id>/helpers/baking_rights?(level=<block_level>)*&(cycle=<block_cycle>)*&(delegate=<pkh>)*&[max_priority=<int>]&[all]
```

> Retrieves the list of delegates allowed to bake a block. By default,
>    it gives the best baking priorities for bakers that have at least one
>    opportunity below the 64th priority for the next block. Parameters
>    `level` and `cycle` can be used to specify the (valid) level(s) in the
>    past or future at which the baking rights have to be returned.
>    Parameter `delegate` can be used to restrict the results to the given
>    delegates. If parameter `all` is set, all the baking opportunities for
>    each baker at each level are returned, instead of just the first one.
>    Returns the list of baking slots. Also returns the minimal timestamps
>    that correspond to these slots. The timestamps are omitted for levels
>    in the past, and are only estimates for levels later that the next
>    block, based on the hypothesis that all predecessor blocks were baked
>    at the first priority.
>
> Optional query arguments:
>
> level = 
>   cycle =  
>   delegate = 
>   max_priority =  all

Source:
https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-helpers-baking-rights