# Can I quickly see all "priority" baking-rights for a cycle?

Tags: tzscan, baking-rights

How is the `Av. Priority` column for baker and endorser, as seen on https://tzscan.io, determined? Is https://tzscan.io simply monitoring all listed bakers in real time?

Can I use a command line tool like `tezos-client` to quickly determine the operations for one or more cycles where my baker/endorser received baking rights (which I assume is what is meant by "priority")?

I realize that I can check baking rights for an individual block as per [How do I get a list of baking rights for a wallet address using the RPC API?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-baking-rights-for-a-wallet-address-using-the-rpc-api). I'm looking for a way to  calculate average priority for the current cycle or a range of past cycles.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-baking-rights-for-a-wallet-address-using-the-rpc-api/420#420

Comment: Aha.. so "Priority" here really means "prioritized in the stack of potential bakers/endorsers" for a block, right? And tzscan is averaging these over the cycle.

Comment: Your use of the word Transaction is misleading. A transaction is a transfer between accounts, whereas you are discussing about baking and endorsement operations.